# Using MongoDB::command to query

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm reading `MongoDB::command` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php), but they see quite poor to me. How can I use `::command` to query a collection?

Lets say I have a collection of `things` and each thing has a `path` (an alpha-numerical string of IDs of other `things` joined with `/`). How would I query all the `things` that starts with `/2e3r4t/`?

Maybe

```
::command(["path" => "/^/2e3r4t//"])
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB::command is used to send raw [database commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) to the server. For most common commands, you will find a wrapper in your language library.

Here, given your description, you need [Collection::find](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) instead. something *like* that (untested -- beware of typos):

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'thing');

$regex = new MongoRegex("/^\/2e3r4t\//");
$collection->find(array('path' => $regex));
```

Amusingly enough, as of MongoDB 3.0.2, the `find` command is not documented, and apparently is *not yet implemented* as a DB command:

```
> db.runCommand({find: "w"})
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "find command not yet implemented" }
```

So, for this one, you will have to rely on the corresponding method of your driver.

---

EDIT: from a quick [look at the sources](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.1.1/src/mongo/db/commands/find_cmd.cpp), the find command was implemented between 3.1.0 and 3.1.1:

- https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/4049c8328c98d8eb2b84fffca43ff4904e936909

Comment: @alexandernst As of 3.0.2 this is not yet supported.